# Publish NetCore App on IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, asp.net-core-mvc

I am getting this error while configuring the NetCore App on IIS7 with App Pool [Framework: No Managed Code]

> "The configuration section 'aspNetCore' cannot be read because it is
>   missing a section declaration"

Please if somebody has a solution to this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you install the .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle on the server?

Comment: Yes I did, can you provide me a link of .net core  hosting bundle, just to make sure I installed the right one. Thanks.

Comment: Refer this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis#install-the-net-core-windows-server-hosting-bundle

Comment: Thank you, let me check on that.

Comment: So It worked, but IIS has to be 7.5 or >

Answer (score 0):

check your OS version, if you can upgarde your iis version.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/windows-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x

Comment: Hi @hassan.ef thank you for answering. Can you provide some details why you think upgrading to a new version will answer the question

Comment: when I use iis7 I had some  problems almost two years ago in .net core configuration  but when upgrade iis version to iis8 that problems solved, if you can use the other system with iis8 and test it.